# React native create new app issue - npm exited with non-zero code: 1

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install

expo init test111
? Choose a template: expo-template-tabs
Using npm to install packages. You can pass --yarn to use Yarn instead.
Extracting project files...
Customizing project...
Unable to initialize git repo. `git` not in PATH.
Installing dependencies...

> npm install
>   npm WARN deprecated deep-assign@3.0.0: Check out `lodash.merge` or `merge-options` instead.
>   npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
>   npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
>   npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
>   npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
>   npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/naver/hammer.js.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mkame\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-02-16T22_14_16_693Z-debug.log

npm exited with non-zero code: 1
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.

Comment: Please format your code/error using backticks like so:
```
code
```

Comment: It isn't clear to me what your question is. Could you add a clarifying description. What are you trying to do? What happened?

Answer (score 1):

`rm -rf node_modules/`
`npm install`

Try removing node modules and reinstall it. This worked for me.